# War installation fails because Image Magic Home Environment Variable Isn't set (though I claim otherwise)

Tags: tomcat, grails, imagemagick, centos, war

Being an (extreme) newbie to grails/groovy/maven/tomcat etc, I endeavoured to set up a CentOS box to run a grails app. I am using VMWare Fusion, CentOS 5.8, Grails 1.3.2, ImageMagick-6.2.8, Tomcat 6.0.35. I opted to install Sun's Java.

After generating my War file, I copy it into Tomcat's webapps directory.

It's at that point that I see the following error generated in catalina.out:

```
2012-03-28 08:00:20,676 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] ERROR context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Please set Image Magic Home environment variable first
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Please set Image Magic Home environment variable first
    at SendFaxService.(SendFaxService.groovy:41)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
```

I believe the relevant part of the error is:  **Please set Image Magic Home environment variable first**

With that in mind, I did `yum install ImageMagick`. I googled Image Magic Environment variable, and saw one called '$MAGICK_HOME', so I executed `export MAGICK_HOME="/usr/share/ImageMagick-6.2.8"`, and also put it in root's .bashrc file. Upon restart, it seems both my user and root can do an `echo $MAGICK_HOME` and get the proper value.

I still get the same error lines generated when I put the war file into the webapps folder.

So I ask you kind internet denizen, what did i do to deserve this?

Actually, just tell me how to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Since you've done the obvious, I'd suggest checking all of the "is it plugged in?" sort of things. What user does tomcat run under? Perhaps it's neither your user nor root? Is the value that you are setting for $MAGICK_HOME correct? Once those things are checked, I'd echo the value of $MAGICK_HOME from the top of tomcat/bin/catalina.sh

Comment: Thanks @GreyBeardedGeek! This suggestion led me to the solution, though I have no idea why. I added 'echo `/usr/bin/whoami`' to the top of catalina.sh, and it tells me 'root'. root can definitely see the MAGICK_HOME path from the command line, so I don't understand why I had to resort exporting the path at the top of the catalina.sh file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though Tomcat was running as root, and root can see the MAGICK_HOME environment variable, Tomcat still couldn't when it tried to install the war that was dependent on ImageMagick.

I added the export statement directly to the top of catalina.sh:

```
export MAGICK_HOME=/usr/share/ImageMagick-6.2.8
```

Voila, it worked. There is probably a better solution, which doesn't involve such unabashed hackery. Please submit it and I'll gladly mark it as the best solution.

Comment: services started upon boot doesn't run root's  .bashrc no matter what, and most services try to clean their environment so they can be run in the same environment regardless of how it's started. modifying catalina.sh is not that bad, though customization like this should be done in a file called setenv.sh in the tomcat bin/ directory (create it if it does not exist)